# Go Gin Gonic Unit Tests in Sub Folder

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-gin

I have a Go API built using the Gin framework.

Reading the docs in the testing section [here](https://gin-gonic.com/docs/testing/), i tried to implement something similar:

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "mes/routes"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func setupMainRoutes(engine *gin.Engine) {
    engine.GET("/mesg/:language/services", routes.AllServices)
    engine.GET("/mesg/:language/service/:id", routes.OneService)
    engine.GET("/mesg/:language/services/search", routes.SearchService)
}

func setupErrorRoutes(engine *gin.Engine) {
    engine.NoRoute(routes.Error404Handler)
}

func setupServer() *gin.Engine {
    // Gin Mode
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

    // Creates the Gin Engine
    engine := gin.New()

    // Setup the API Routes
    setupMainRoutes(engine)

    // Setup Error Routes
    setupErrorRoutes(engine)

    // Return engine
    return engine
}

func main() {
// Run the engine
setupServer().Run()
}
```

main_test.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

/************** Error Handling Tests **************/
func TestPing404Errors1Of3(t *testing.T) {
    router := setupServer()

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
    router.ServeHTTP(w, req)

    assert.Equal(t, 404, w.Code)
}
```

However, it seems that I cannot move the `main_test.go` to another folder because the `setupServer()` function becomes undefined.

Is there a way to classify all my tests in a sub folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Moving `main_test.go` to another folder means that you will be testing/calling `setupServer()` from a different package. For that, you would need to export as `SetupServer()` and import the package which contain `SetupServer()` in your test file. Unfortunately you can't do that with your current file structure because we can't import `package main`. Therefore, you need to rename the package if you really want to do so.

Having said that, putting the test files `_test.go` in the same directory (hence same package) is a common practice in Go.